# Prove that. $G/Z(G)\cong S_3$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

$M=\left(\begin{array}{ll}0 & i \\ i & 0\end{array}\right), N=\left(\begin{array}{ll}\omega & 0 \\ 0 & \omega^{2}\end{array}\right)$ and $G=<M, N>$ be the group generated by M,N
Here $\omega$ is cube root of unity

Prove that. $G/Z(G)\cong S_3$

What i tried

I look for relations that this generated group has

I find.  $M^4= I $ identity matrix ,
$ N^3=I$, and. $ MN\neq NM $
$\implies  G$  is non -abelian $ \implies Z(G)= \{I\} $
Work reduced to show $G\cong S_3$

But this is not possible as
G has element  ,M of order 4
But  $S_3$  has only elements of order 1,2,3

Is  i am doing it correctly ??

If   i right please  tell me the group to which G isomorphic

Comment: What about $M^2=-I$? Surely it is in the centre?

Comment: @ancientmathematician Yes sir $M^2$   is in center is there any other ?

Comment: The generating relations are $M^4=N^3=I, MNM^{-1}=N^{-1}$. I hope this helps.

Comment: G has 12 elements! And center has 2 elements Factor group G/Z(G) has order 6 . There are two gropus of order 6 upto isomorphism $\mathbb{Z}_6$ or $ S_3$ , can you move from there?

Comment: Please do not write "yes sir"!

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**  $$G/Z(G)\cong{\rm Inn}\; G.$$  (Apparently) there are six inner automorphisms of $G$, and they don't all commute.  Why not try to find them?

Once you find them, which isn't too difficult, you know the group has size six, if you can just establish that $G$ has order at most twelve, and that there is a non-identity element of the center.

As suggested by the comments, there should be a surjective homomorphism from the group with presentation $\langle m,n\mid m^3,n^4,nmn^{-1}m^{-2}\rangle$ to $G$.  Thus $G$ has order at most twelve.